# Confusion with the behavior of HAVING clause

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I am not able to understand the behavior of the following query:

```
select max(avg(salary)) from employees
group by first_name
having avg(salary) >= max(salary);
```

It prints out the result as **17000**. But if max(salary) is **24000** shouldn't there be empty result. If I replace "">="" with ">" it prints the result as **NULL**.

And if I replace ">=" with "<", then 13100 is printed in the result.

Below is the employees table:

```
TJ      2100
Steven  2200
Hazel   2200
James   2400
Ki      2400
Karen   2500
James   2500
Joshua  2500
Peter   2500
Martha  2500
Randall 2500
Guy     2600
Randall 2600
Donald  2600
Douglas 2600
Irene   2700
John    2700
Sigal   2800
Mozhe   2800
Girard  2800
Vance   2800
Shelli  2900
Michael 2900
Timothy 2900
Anthony 3000
Kevin   3000
Alex    3100
Curtis  3100
Jean    3100
Alana   3100
Julia   3200
Stephen 3200
Winston 3200
Samuel  3200
Laura   3300
Jason   3300
Julia   3400
Trenna  3500
Renske  3600
Jennife 3600
Kelly   3800
Britney 3900
Sarah   4000
Alexis  4100
Diana   4200
Nandita 4200
Jennife 4400
David   4800
Valli   4800
Kevin   5800
Bruce   6000
Pat     6000
Sundita 6100
Amit    6200
Charles 6200
Sundar  6400
Shanta  6500
Susan   6500
David   6800
Luis    6900
Oliver  7000
Sarath  7000
Kimbe   7000
Mattea  7200
Eliza   7300
William 7400
Nanette 7500
Louise  7500
Ismael  7700
Jose    7800
Payam   7900
Matthew 8000
Christ  8000
Lindsey 8000
John    8200
Adam    8200
William 8300
Jack    8400
Jonath  8600
Alyssa  8800
Alex    9000
Daniel  9000
Peter   9000
Allan   9000
Patrick 9500
Danie   9500
David   9500
Tayler  9600
Hermann 10000
Harris  10000
Janette 10000
Peter   10000
Clara   10500
Eleni   10500
Gerald  11000
Den     11000
Ellen   11000
Lisa    11500
Alberto 12000
Shelley 12008
Nancy   12008
Michael 13000
Karen   13500
John    14000
Lex     17000
Neena   17000
Steven  24000
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  In plain English, _describe_ what output you are trying get.

Comment: 10 rows of sample data is usually enough. Also show us the expected result - because I can't understand what you want.

Comment: You can check `avg(salary) >= max(salary)` and `avg(salary) = max(salary)`, the result should be same.  For example, if you have only 1 record - let say 3000, then both `avg` and `max` are 3000.  BTW, I believe you use `group by FirstName` to calculate `avg` and `max`.

Comment: `MAX` on `AVG`? Is this Oracle? It's the only DBMS I know of supporting this shortcut syntax. As to the answer: see Mit Bhatt's explanation. For every unique first name `AVG` = `MAX`. The additional `MAX` gets you the maximum of these.

Comment: Well my question is that:

Why is 17000 printed out, while as max(salary) is 24000.

Comment: 24000 is Steven's salary, and Steven's avg salary is 13100. So avg(salary)>=max(salary) evaluates to false

Answer (score 3):

You are doing Group By `First_name`, in your table,

For Neena, `max(salary) = 17000` and `avg(salary)=17000`,

So, `>=` matches the condition in the query and `17000` is returned.

Where as replacing `>=` with `>` evaulated to NULL.

For Steven, Max(salary)=24000, AVG(salary)=(24000+2200)/2=13100

So replacing `>=` with `<` returns `13100`

> Note : Grouping by ColumnName here `first_name` plays the key role
>   here. All the aggregate functions in SELECT as well as having clause,
>   are applied per employee and not on the whole table.

Comment: How about the TJ isn't his/her max(salary) =2100 and avg(salary) = 2100. And there are other such employees as well.

Comment: You have selected `max(avg(salary))` which is 17000

Comment: So you mean that max(salary) in this case evaluates to max(avg(salary))?

Also, for James max(salary) = 2500, avg(salary) = 2450. So even James seems to be a candidate for the output in case of <.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare an employee's mean salary (does this really make sense?  Surely an employee only has one salary at a point in time?) then this might help

```
WITH
 employees (first_name,salary)
 AS
  (SELECT 'TJ',2100 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Steven',2200 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Hazel',2200 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'James',2400 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Ki',2400 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Karen',2500 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'James',2500 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Joshua',2500 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Peter',2500 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Martha',2500 FROM dual 
  )
SELECT
 first_name
,mean_salary_all_emps
,AVG(salary)
FROM
 (SELECT
   first_name
  ,salary
  ,AVG(salary) OVER ()  mean_salary_all_emps
  FROM
   employees
 )
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY 
 first_name
,mean_salary_all_emps
HAVING  AVG(salary) > mean_salary_all_emps
;
```